# Sharepoint 2013 access with /_vti_bin/listdata.svc

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest, sharepoint

I'm really not experienced in this subject, and I can't seem to find out where to quite start.

I'm trying to read data from a list on SharePoint 13 (365 Preview) into a WinRT App. I added a Service Reference to mysite.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc and it added correctly. From there I built this wrapper for getting the a list asynchronously:

```
private Task<IEnumerable<MyListItems>> GetMyListAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IEnumerable<MyListItems>>();
    var sharepointContext =
        new WelcomescreentestTeamSiteDataContext(
            new Uri("https://mysite.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"))
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user.name", "pass.word", "mysite.onmicrosoft.com")
        }; ;
    try
    {
        sharepointContext.MyList.BeginExecute(asyncResult =>
        {
            try
            {
                var result = sharepointContext.MyList.EndExecute(asyncResult);
                tcs.TrySetResult(result);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!tcs.TrySetException(ex))
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }, new object());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        tcs.TrySetException(ex);
        tcs.SetCanceled();
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

I've changed the username / domain around quite a bit, but nothing seems to work.

What's the right approach here?

I've built in a SAML-based security approach which works, but I'm still wondering why this isn't working.

Comment: Hi SBOSS, not sure what is meant by 'nothing seems to work'. Is the request fired? does it contain credentials? Also, i'd like to see the source for WelcomescreentestTeamSiteDataContext to be able to advise further.

Comment: I'm currently working on something else, and will return to modify the question once I have the time for it.